# Update database table column - Laravel

Tags: laravel, edit

I am using spatie to assign and give permissions to user roles.

I need to update the `role_id` column in `model_has_roles` table.

I tried using eloquent but unfortunately there is no model for the tables created under the spatie migrations.

Right now I am using the below function to update:

```
    $user_role = DB::table('model_has_roles')
        ->where('model_id', '=', $request->userid)  
        ->select('model_has_roles.*')
        ->get();

    $user_role->role_id = $request->userid;
    $user_role->save();
```

But this says that `"Method save does not exist"`

Any advice on how to update the database column?

Comment: DB::table()->get() returns stdClass objects, they don't have methods on them.  Did you read the docs here: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission#using-permissions-via-roles?

Comment: How can I write the update query then?

Comment: Write an update query...  If you don't use Eloquent Models, you won't have access to  the ORM methods.   Might want to make sure you read through the Laravel docs and the spatie permission docs so you understand more about what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there are no Eloquent models, this cannot use the ORM methods as @Devon said in the comments. I used the below update query and it worked fine.

```
DB::table('model_has_roles')
->where('model_id', $request->userid)
->update(['role_id' =>  $request->editusertype]);
```