# Write a new line arrow into a model_has_role_table Spatie Laravel

Tags: laravel, roles

i am using Spatie in Laravel 8, I tried using eloquent but unfortunately there is no model for the tables created under the spatie migrations.
I am trying to excecute a line like this

```
DB::table('model_has_roles')->insert(['role_id' => 1, 'model_type' => 'App\Models\User' ,'model_id' => 4]);
```

i inserted this line into RegisterController.php in function create

```
 protected function create(array $data)
{

  DB::table('model_has_roles')->insert(['role_id' => 1, 'model_type' => 'App\Models\User' ,'model_id' => 4]);


    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

When a register a new user i got the following error

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tcsnpedro`.`model_has_roles`, CONSTRAINT `model_has_roles_role_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `model_has_roles` (`role_id`, `model_type`, `model_id`) values (1, App\Models\User, 4))

what does this error mean?

I found this interesting article [Update database table column - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52988542/update-database-table-column-laravel)
where a person do an update of the "model_has_roles" table, and i guess he succeeded doing this.
where should i put the following DB code?

```
 DB::table('model_has_roles')->insert(['role_id' => 1, 'model_type' => 'App\Models\User' ,'model_id' => 4]);
```

Should i create a new laravel model in order to create and update information into the model_has_role spatie table?

Comment: So... Laravel by default has the `User` model and you could create your relation to the roles table there. Then `sync` or `attach` your roles to the user. Doesn't Spatie publish their models? Anyway, try to do it through the User model first. Inserting into a pivot table is not the best way. You're missing part of the foreign key which is the `role`: it doesn't exist in the roles table

Comment: The error tells Role is not available with id = 1 in Role table. So you need to create a role first and after that you can assign role_id into model_has_roles table.

Comment: i tried to update role information that i already have loaded in 'model_has_roles'  using DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('model_id', 1)->update(['role_id' => 1]); and i got the same error

Comment: Thank you very much NIKUNJ KOTHIYA now i can add arrow lines to the model_has_roles, and thank you UnderDog for the important recomendations